Solving a boundary value problem with an integral constraint.
EDIT1: Initial post left as it, but modified below to answer comments
EDIT2: the proper problem (see EDIT1) was ill-posed close to the right boundary, preventing convergence of the BVP. Changing the formulation to an IVP with 2 unknown parameters and 2 additional constraints as suggested by @whpowell96 worked.
I want to solve a boundary value problem that can be stated as:
$$h' = F(h)$$
$$h'' = G(h, h')$$
with $h(1) = 0$, $h'(0) = 0$ and
$$\int_{0}^{1} H(h) = 1/2$$
After looking for some solutions, a typical one seems to be adding the integral to the ODE:
$$h' = F(h)$$
$$h'' = G(h, h')$$
$$q' = H(h)$$
with $h(1) = 0$, $h'(0) = 0$ , $q(0) = 0$ and $q(1) = 1/2$, with
$$q(x)=\int_{0}^{x} H(h)$$.
However, this implies that the last column of the jacobian of the system is always 0 as neither $F$, $G$ or $H$ explicitly depends on $q$. Hence, trying to solve this with typical two points bvp solvers using collocation methods, such as this one in python fails as the jacobian is singular.
This seems to be a widely spread method, but adding the integral as a new unknown in the problem seems to always lead to a singular jacobian.
What am I missing?

It seems I have strongly badly written the system I am working with in an attempt to simplify it. Here is a better description of the set of equations I am working with:
$$ \mathcal{F}(h, h', h'', x, p1, p2) = 0 \quad (1)$$
where $h$ is a function of $x$ and $p1$, $p2$ are unknown constants part of the problem. I also have the following constraints:

$h(0) = 1$
$h'(0) = 0$
$h(1) = \mathcal{G}(p1, p2)$
$\int_{0}^{1} \mathcal{H}(h) = 1/2$.

Luckily, $\mathcal{F}$ allows me to isolate $h'' = \mathcal{F}_{2}(h', h, p1, p2)$, such that to approach this, I have re-written this whole system as:
$$\frac{d h}{dx} = h' \quad (2)$$
$$\frac{d h'}{dx} = \mathcal{F}_{2}(h', h, p1, p2) \quad (3)$$
$$q' = H(h) \quad (4)$$
with $h(0) = 1$, $h(1) = \mathcal{G}(p1, p2)$, $h'(0) = 0$ , $q(0) = 0$ and $q(1) = 1/2$ and with
$$q(x)=\int_{0}^{x} H(h)$$.
This gives me a first-order system with 3 unknown functions + 2 unknown and 5 boundary conditions, which I believe to be properly constrained?

Are you sure this problem is even well-posed? The first equations can be simplified to $h'' = G(h,F(h))$ with two BCs which often has a unique solution. Adding an integral constraint may overdetermine the problem

@whpowell96 : It is even worse, $h'=F(h)$ already completely determines $h$, the second equation is either superfluous or conflicting, preventing convergence of the BVP solver. Additional conflict is then in the supernumerary boundary conditions.

Ah, you are right. I missed that upon first read. This problem is massively overdetermined.

@LutzLehmann  It seems I have strongly badly written the system I am working with in an attempt to simplify it. Please see my edited post -- I believe the (properly written system) is not overdetermined ?

$h'' = F(h',h,p_1,p_1)$ has a unique solution given just $h(0)$ and $h'(0)$. The system is still overdetermined

@whpowell96 $p1$ and $p2$ are unknown parameters that I want o solve along $h$, so I believe it requires two additional constraints ?

The properties of the Jacobian do not translate directly to the properties of the system for the boundary value problem.
In the most simple case of the Euler method the big system has blocks according to
$$
x_{k+1}=x_k+hF(x_k),
$$
which gives
$$
[\;I+hF'(x_k)\;|\;I\;]
$$
in the rows for $x_k$ and columns for $(x_k,x_{k+1})$. As far as single blocks influence the quality of the whole, it is whether $I+hF'(x_k)$ is close to singular. This is related to the stability of the method, and if it is to easy to reach this situation, the ODE is stiff (for explicit methods).
With other methods you get variations of that block structure, but the relation to stability remains the same.
As for solve_bvp, it is not very sophisticated, it's a proof-of-concept or experimental implementation without guard-rails and heuristics (except for the subdivision refinement). You need to provide an initial guess that looks very much like the actual solution, otherwise you enter a global-search phase where divergence may occur which often leads to singular Jacobians, or unlimited refinements of the subdivision.

Thanks for this clarification. A couple additional questions. Is there a way of quantifying the stiffness of a system of equation? Do you have any other method (or even better, solver) than the one employed by solve_bvp that you could advise ? I believe my initial guess is the best that I could provide (I use a trivial solution found by setting one of the known parameters of the system to 0, while its proper value is nonzero but small).

One measure is the condition number of the Jacobian along the solution path or in some neighborhood of it. But that is impractical, so usually it is detected on the behavior of the step size control. // No, if it works, it is the best solver available. // As was commented, your system is somewhat strange. Remember that the number of boundary condition slots is equal to the number of components of the state, variable and constant components combined, which you have indeed satisfied in your last version.

It seems I can not get solve_bvp to work ... So I might look into a shooting method on a fixed grid instead. Do you still feel that this system is somewhat strange in the last version? Otherwise, do you have another suggestion to solve the differential equation (1) aside turning all of this into a first order system as I did ?

Given the new formulation in the edit, notice that $h(t)$ is uniquely determined by the initial conditions and $p_1$ and $p_2$. Therefore this problem is not really a BVP, but is a nonlinear system in $p_1$ and $p_2$.
Define the function $f:(p_1,p_2)\mapsto \left(\int_0^1 \mathcal{H}(h(x;p_1,p_2))\mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{2},\mathcal{G}(p_1,p_2)-h(1)\right)^T$. Then the solution to your problem satisfies $f(p_1,p_2) = 0\in\mathbb{R}^2$. If you have a reasonable guess for $p_1$ and $p_2$, you can feed this to a nonlinear solver such as optimize.root in SciPy. This function has various methods available, such as a hybrid Powell method (default) or Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm.
Notice that the evaluation of $f$ as written requires solving an initial value problem for $h$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Because of this and the small size of the problem, it will be much easier to use these methods without providing an explicit Jacobian matrix. However, if the nonlinearity is difficult to the point that these methods are having a hard time converging, then providing an explicit Jacobian matrix may help.
In this case, the Jacobian can be computed directly as
$$
Jf(p_1,p_2) = \begin{pmatrix}\int_0^1\mathcal{H}'(h(x;p_1,p_2))s_1(x)~\mathrm{d}x & \int_0^1\mathcal{H}'(h(x;p_1,p_2))s_2(x)~\mathrm{d}x \\ \frac{\partial \mathcal{G}}{\partial p_1}(p_1,p_2) - s_1(1) & \frac{\partial\mathcal{G}}{\partial p_2}(p_1,p_2) - s_2(1) \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are solutions to the sensitivity equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_1'' &= \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}_2}{\partial h'}s_1' + \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}_2}{\partial h}s_1 + \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}_2}{\partial p_1}, \quad s_1(0) = s_1'(0) = 0 \\
s_2'' &= \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}_2}{\partial h'}s_2' + \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}_2}{\partial h}s_2 + \frac{\partial \mathcal{F}_2}{\partial p_2}, \quad s_2(0) = s_2'(0) = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here I have suppressed the dependence on $(h',h,p_1,p_2)$ in the derivatives of $\mathcal{F}_2$ for brevity. These equations are obtained by differentiating the original IVP w.r.t. $p_1$ and $p_2$ and denoting $s_i = \frac{\partial h}{\partial p_i}$. Notice that these equations are also IVPs that depend on $h$, so they can be appended to the original IVP system and computed concurrently with $h$ as a $6$-dimensional IVP. This will likely not provide too much additional computational burden since the dimensions are so small. Adjoint-based methods are another option to compute these derivatives, but they will likely be less efficient on this system as solving a $6$-dimensional IVP is comparable to solving two $2$-dimensional IVPs in serial.
I would also like to mention that you can apply your original idea of appending the equation $q' = \mathcal{H}(t), \ q(0)=0$ to the original IVP. In this formulation, we would also have a corresponding sensitivity $r_i = \frac{\partial q}{\partial p_i}$ and sensitivity equation $r'_i = \mathcal{H}'(h)s_i, \ r_i(0)=0$ and the Jacobian would look like
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(p_1,p_2) &= \left(q(1)-\frac{1}{2},\mathcal{G}(p_1,p_2)-h(1)\right)^T\\
Jf(p_1,p_2) &= \begin{pmatrix}r_1(1) & r_2(1) \\ \frac{\partial \mathcal{G}}{\partial p_1}(p_1,p_2) - s_1(1) & \frac{\partial\mathcal{G}}{\partial p_2}(p_1,p_2) - s_2(1) \end{pmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thanks ! The problem was actually ill-posed close to the right boundary, hence explaining why solving it as a BVP problem did not work. Shifting to an IVP with 2 unknown parameters as you suggested worked.
